# PHP generated html form not giving response

Tags: php, html, forms

I was creating a page which will create a number of html forms in it's body using a php for loop and each form will submit the response to the page itself. But after creating it the webpage is looking fine, but none of the forms are working. Here is a picture of the page.
[Webpage is looking completely fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWvby.png)

And the code is here.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Dhaka");

    if(!isset($_SESSION["user"])||$_SESSION["user"]!="shihan04"){
        echo "<script> location.href=\"https://sgtcmc.000webhostapp.com/contests/index.php\";</script>";
    }

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
        $pp = $_POST["pp"];
        $rep = test_input($_POST["rep"]);
        $dn = test_input($_POST["dn"]);
        $dir=getcwd()."/clarifications/";
        $fa=fopen($dir.$dn,"r");
        $unm=fgets($fa);$ppb=fgets($fa);$tm=fgets($fa);$sub=fgets($fa);$qs=fgets($fa);$repb=fgets ($fa);
        fclose($fa);
        $fa=fopen($dir.$dn,"w");
        fwrite($fa,$unm.$pp."\n".$tm.$sub.$qs.$rep);
        fclose($fa);
    }

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Clarification Response</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script>MathJax = {tex: {inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']]},svg: {fontCache: 'global'}};</script>
    <script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-svg.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>
    <?php
    $ad=getcwd()."/clarifications/";
    $af=scandir($ad,1);
    $ac=count($af)-2;
    for($i=0;$i<$ac;$i++){
        $fa=fopen($ad.$af[$i],"r");
        $unm=fgets($fa);$pp=fgets($fa);$tm=fgets($fa);$sub=fgets($fa);$qs=fgets($fa);$rep=fgets($fa);
        fclose($fa);
        echo "<table class=\"table-sm table-bordered\">
            <tr><th>Username</th><td>".$unm."</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Time</th><td>".$tm."</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Subject</th><td>".$sub."</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Question</th><td>".$qs."</td></tr>
        </table>";
        echo "<div class=\"container-sm\">
            <form method=\"post\" action=\"".htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])."\">
                <div class=\"form-group\">";
        if($pp=="1\n"){
            echo "<select class=\"form-control\" id=\"pp\" name=\"pp\">
                    <option value=\"1\">Public</option>
                    <option value=\"0\">Private</option>";
        }
        else{
            echo "<select class=\"form-control\" id=\"pp\" name=\"pp\">
                    <option value=\"0\">Private</option>
                    <option value=\"1\">Public</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>
                </div>";
        echo "<div class=\"form-group\">
                  <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"dn\" value=\"".$af[$i]."\" disabled>
              </div>
              <div class=\"form-group\">
                  <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Reply\" name=\"rep\" value=\"".$rep."\">
              </div>
              <input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" class=\"btn btn-outline-primary\">
              </form></div><br>";
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

I can't find the solution for this and I need to fix this in next 2-3 days. I'm a complete noob. So please help me with this.

Comment: What means "none of the forms are working"? Are the forms submitting? Or it's fails to retrieving data?

Comment: The forms aren't submitting.

Comment: Actually I can't detect that. But the form handling code is not getting called I can assure you that.